# Приведение к общему знаменателю в Конструкторе класса

Tags: c++

Задача.

На входе я получаю две обыкновенные дроби a/b c/d. Мне нужно потом их сравнить, не переводя в десятичный вид. 
Могу ли я в конструкторе их сразу привести к общему знаменателю, т.е.  (a*d)/(b*d) и (c*b)/(b*d), или где это сделать?

Как это сделать?

Вот мой класс:

```
typedef long long int ll_int;// число будет 10^9

class Fraction{    
public:
    ll_int x, y;
    Fraction (ll_int x, ll_int y): x(x), y(y){}
    Fraction (){}        
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &out, Fraction s){
        out << s.x << "/" << s.y;
        return out;
    }
    void read(){
        char s[30] = {};
        cin >> s;
        char *ptr = strtok(s, "/");
        x = atoll(ptr);
        ptr = strtok(nullptr, "\0");
        y = atoll(ptr);
    }
```

Comment: Я бы для Вашей задачи переписал бы операторы сравнения

Comment: О каком "общем" знаменателе может идти речь, если конструктор у вас работает с *одной* дробью?

Comment: AnT Да, я это понимаю, поэтому и спрашиваю, как это сделать и где это сделать?

Comment: Александр Муксимов , оператор сравнения, я добавлю, но мне не хочется в этом операторе проводить приведение к общему знаменателю, так как он булевый.

Comment: Как один из способов, объявить оператор сравнения дружественным и там уже проводить привидение к общему знаменателю.